# Array picture storing on MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to store pictures (.jpg) in my table on MS SQL. What type of column I need to choose?
If I always store three pictures, is there any array type in MS SQL to store in one column all
three pictures ( like array in Oracle) ?

Answer (score 1):

`SQL Server 2008` supports [`FILESTREAM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx): it's almost like a file pointer but is subject to transaction and access control.

`SQL Server` does not support arrays. If you always store three images, why don't you create three fields for them?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `varbinary(max)` to hold an image. It's controversial, but I find it makes my life easier: the images are part of each database backup or copy operation. (This is also an argument *against* this approach, especially if you have terabytes of images.)

As another poster points out, one of the new options for this datatype is `FILESTREAM`. It looks good but I haven't had a chance to try it out myself.

- There's no array type in MS SQL.

Comment: `VARBINARY` uses `SQL Server`'s cache, `FILESTREAM` uses `NTFS` cache. Both are subject to backup.